# How to add custom field in ExpressionEngine publish entry

Tags: custom-fields

I need to add a custom field in the publish entry area (specifically in the date tab). 
Should I use the Control Panel class or is there a preferred method?

Answer (score 1):

> > If I understood correctly, you need to add an extra field to an already existing channel and you can easily do that from the CP by going to Admin > **Channel**
> > **Administration > Channel Fields**.
>
> Browse and click on the channel that you want to add your custom field
> to and create a new channel field.
>
> To put your field under the Date tab:
>
> Refer to this http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/cp/content/publish_page_layouts.html

Comment: Sorry about the miss understanding , I meant adding field using programming not for specific channel , I need to add a field which uses javascript in the publish entry section using php

Comment: In that case, I'd say you either create a simple field in the publish area normally and use this plugin [CP JS](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/cp-css-js) to create the javascript functionality that you want to assign to it.

Comment: I need to customize one the "publish entry form" fields , "entry date" field which is in the "date" tab section of publish entry , I have to change the normal behavior of this field. I'm writing an extension and trying to change this field's behavior using hooks , but I have no good clue on this!? any suggestions?